# Can you create a standalone program using the QGIS API? (Not QGIS Plugin.)

Tags: qgis, python, c#

Can you create a standalone program using the QGIS API? (Not QGIS Plugin.)

The functions of QGIS that our team uses are limited, so I would like to create a GUI by collecting only the functions that we use a lot.

For example, if I type the layer path in the program I'm creating and press the "Merger Layer" button, QGIS will merge the layers and bring the result to the program I created and display it on the screen.

Is this possible? Since it is the first time to start development, I wonder if it is a work that can be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is documented in the PyQGIS dev cookbook:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications

in short, you write a Python script that imports the parts of QGIS that you need, usually `qgis.core` and then work with functions and classes from that.